# installing packages in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, package

I'm a beginner with Mathematica 9 and was trying to install a package that does an inverse Laplace transform. I tried the instructions on Wolfram website which is mainly: File -> install, the install window opens, select the package source, and give it a name, and click OK. I did exactly that but when I type the Needs command, I get the following answer:
Needs::nocont: "Context "talb` was not created when Needs was evaluated."
Any suggestion on how to properly install a package?
regards

Comment: note that the package I'm trying to install and use could be found on the following link
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5026/

Comment: some of those packages have not been maintained to be compatible with current versions ( look at the date 2003 ). You should try mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are saving this file under the addOns folder and then  execute << FixedTalbotNumericalLaplaceInversion in your mathematica notebook.